# configure iam authorizer in SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam-cli

I want to control access to my api gateway fronting lambda with iam permissions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

I have seen no examples of how to configure this in a sam template. What does a sam template look like that has authorizationType property set to AWS_IAM?

I think I read somewhere that Sam doesn't support this directly but you can do it with swagger? Can I use swagger to get around this limitation? I haven't found a simple example of that.

Comment: this works with swagger even though its not supported natively yet via template

Answer (score 0):

The SAM template for `AWS::Serverless::Api` does not provide the authorizationType. You could instead use the `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` in your SAM template, but that means you have to define your API Gateway using CloudFormation resource types rather than SAM.

Comment: Not even with swagger?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure, haven't used swagger with SAM before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM` under `Auth:`

Example:

```
Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
```

More: [IAM permission example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-controlling-access-to-apis-permissions.html)